# Is there an entity constraint annotation for property not to be erased

Tags: hibernate, jpa

So after the phone number is set on Person entity, I want to not lose the data by mistake, so I want a validation preferable through annotation, that restricts the phone number to be set to blank or null after it has a value.
Phone numbers can be added much later after the creation of the person entity, so initially, it should allow for a null phone number just not after it has been set.
I could do something in the setter, but I hope for a cleaner annotated way.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do that. It depends if the application or part of the application should check this or if the database should do the check.

If you want to have the database check this you can create a trigger that checks if the update wants to set the phone number to null.

If you want to have Hibernate do this you could create a customer validator but what will you do if someone is setting it to null? Because the validation would throw an exception.

So if you don't want to have the check on the database probably the most save option is what you suggest. To not allow setting the value to null in the setter.